# .htaccess config doesn't hide the php ending

Tags: php, .htaccess

I would like to hide the php ending via the .htaccess file, but this is not possible. (mod_rewrite is enabled)

My .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

## hide .php extension snippet
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Oh, the php page is addressed by form action

Comment: Try adding `QSA` in `[R,L]`: `[R,QSA,L]`

Comment: Please be specific: what exact URL does that form point to?

Comment: You should change the URL referenced in the form action, not rely on a redirect. What *method* are you using with this form? (If you are using POST then the 302 redirect will lose all the POST data.)

Comment: Oh ok, yes I use post, the url structure looks like this: https://example.com (<- form that points to page1.php (also in root folder)) || https://example.com/page1.php (I want to hide only the .php) the url should look like this: https://example.com/page1